# How to reference a 2D array from a static context?

Tags: java, arrays, static, definition

Every time I call `myGrid` in the `generateBoard` method, I get the error:

> non-static variable `myGrid` cannot be referenced from static context

To my understanding, this shouldn't happen, because I've set the array to be public and should be able to be accessed from any other class. So have I set up the array incorrectly?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Zombies {
    private int Level = 1;
    private int MoveNo = 0;
    public int[][] myGrid = new int[12][12];

    public static void generateBoard() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                if ( i == 6 && j == 6) {
                    myGrid[i][j] = 'P';
                }
                if (rand.nextInt(4) == 0) {
                    myGrid[i][j] = 'I';
                }
                myGrid[i][j] = 'x';
            }
        }
    }

    public static String printBoard() {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.print( "| " );
                }
                System.out.print( myGrid[i][j] + " " );
                if (j == 12) {
                    System.out.print( "|" );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, please highlight (with words) the line that is indicated by the error message.  Will make it much easier to home-in on the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myGrid` variable is an instance variable rather than a class variable. That is, it can only be accessed by an instance of `Zombies`. On the other hand, the static methods (and class, a.k.a. static, variables) belong to a class, which are shared, in this case, among all `Zombies` instances.

Either pass `myGrid` (`int[][]`) as parameter to each of these static methods, or declare it as `static`.

Comment: How would I declare the array as a static? Just 'public static int[][] myGrid = new int[12][12];' ?

Comment: Yes, as you wrote. However, at the same time remember, that depending on your design, the array can be passed on a parameter to these methods, or the 2D array can be declared as a class variable (static). If you wish to instantiate the static array (i.e. maybe you wish to populate the values with 10 before having your static methods start working on it), for whatever reason, during declaration, you can use a static block.

Comment: Yeah, it's being used as a game board so I think it would be better to have it statically accessible.